# MS Access: How to use a pulldown combo-box control to populate multiple text fields in a form

Tags: forms, ms-access, textbox, ms-access-2010, subform

There are 3 text fields that require population with column info from a combo-pull down.

[image]

The combo box control is called cmb_ao_owner(1), and the target text fields (to pass column data to) are txt_ao_owner_id(2), txt_ao_owner_phone(3), and txt_ao_owner_email(4) respectively.

The text fields are to be populated with column(1), column(2), and column(3) data respectively. The query from the combo box is:

```
SELECT [dbo_SUP_CONTACTS].[sc_owner_id], [dbo_SUP_CONTACTS].[sc_owner], 
[dbo_SUP_CONTACTS].[sc_work], [dbo_SUP_CONTACTS].[sc_email]
FROM dbo_SUP_CONTACTS ORDER BY [sc_owner];
```

The controls are in a sub-sub-form

```
parent-form: workbench
sub-form: contacts
sub-sub-form: asset_owners
```

..but I now know that it does not matter as the "Me" parameter I think addresses that.

Challenge I'm having is with the syntax to pass the combo data to the text fields in the same row after the update event.

**FIG A: Attempt 1**

```
Private Sub cmb_ao_owner_AfterUpdate()
me.parent.txt_ao_owner_id = [cmb_ao_owner].Column(2)
me.parent.txt_ao_owner_phone = [cmb_ao_owner].Column(3)
me.parent.txt_ao_owner_email = [cmb_ao_owner].Column(4)
End Sub
```

**FIG A: Attempt 2**

```
Private Sub cmb_ao_owner_AfterUpdate()    
Me!txt_ao_owner_id = Me!cmb_ao_owner.Column(2)
Me!txt_ao_owner_phone = Me!cmb_ao_owner.Column(3)
Me!txt_ao_owner_email = Me!cmb_ao_owner.Column(4)
End Sub
```

Each attempt yielded errors. Any suggestions? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What errors? Column index begins with 0. So first column is index 0, etc. Why do you want to duplicate owner info into another table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried this with a quick mock-up...

```
Private Sub Combo0_AfterUpdate()
Me.Text2.Value = Me.Combo0.Column(1)
End Sub
```

Shouldn't `Me!txt_ao_owner_phone` etc. in your examples also contain '.value' or '.text'? Therefore: `Me!txt_ao_owner_phone.Value`

Comment: In VBA, Value is default property of fields and data controls so it is not necessary to explicitly reference. Text would not be appropriate reference.

Comment: Actually what worked was Me.txt_ao_owner_id.Value = Me.cmb_ao_owner.Column(0) Using the "!" and .text caused it to fail. I replaced the string with (dot) and the "Value" and it worked beautifully. Still I give you credit because - silly me forgot to add either (Value, and Text) at the end of my query. Nice catch :)

Comment: @June7 while this is true for some reason I needed to explicitly add the .text or .value suffix for it to work. MS Access (for me at least) is quirky if not particular. Thanks all!

Comment: Suppose there are always exceptions. One I know of involves listbox. Certainly doesn't hurt to be explicit. Still, why are you duplicating data to another table? Text property is only available for control that has focus.